# Touch control not changing for REMOTECONTROL in Google Home

Tags: touch, google-home

I'm using the touch control device type REMOTECONTROL for Google's Smart Home Device.  In google Home the touch device gui only displays the "ONOFF" button at the center of the screen.  Need help in identifying possible errors I have made.   Here is the code fragment of the OnSync reply:

```
        agentUserId: USER_ID,
         "devices": [
           {
             "id": "123",
             "type": "action.devices.types.REMOTECONTROL",
             "traits": [
               "action.devices.traits.AppSelector",
               "action.devices.traits.InputSelector",
               "action.devices.traits.MediaState",
               "action.devices.traits.OnOff",
               "action.devices.traits.TransportControl",
               "action.devices.traits.Channel",
               "action.devices.traits.Volume"
             ],
             "name": {   .....
```

Here are some of the facts:

1. All the traits are working that I've tried,
2. The one touch control showing, the onoff button, on the control does work,
3. The project started using the "LAMP" control to test,
4. Tried other touch devices, just to see if the GUI changed...it didn't,
5. name can change as well as other fields and they all seem to be recognized,
6. Utterances seems to work fine, at least on the Google mini,
7. This touch control is supposed to be supported according to the https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/guides page (so please don't send me there),
8. Tried syncing several times by unlinking control on the phone and relinking,
9. Tried to find the rev number of the "Home" app but couldn't find it.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're only seeing the `OnOff` touch controls because that is currently the only trait in your list [supported for the Home app](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/touch-controls#supported_traits_2).

If you test your Action on a smart display, you should see the touch controls for `Volume` and `Channel`, as those [are supported](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/touch-controls#supported_traits).

The traits should all function as expected with vocal commands.

Comment: Totally didn't understand what that page on touch controls was telling me.  But now it's clear. Thank you for pointing that out.